# LaTeX issues Undefined control sequence \Chaptername

Tags: macros, errors, fancyhdr

We're back again with the undefined control sequence error, but this time I am not capable of finding it. It is something related with the header and footer:

```
\let\Chaptermark\chaptermark
\def\chaptermark#1{\def\Chaptername{#1}\Chaptermark{#1}}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\small \emph{Text}}
\fancyhead[R]{\small Text}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\small \thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{\small \emph{Chapter \thechapter. \Chaptername}}
```

**AND** Log report (near the error message):

```
]) (./Chapters/02_Abstract.tex) [2] [3

] (./Report.toc [4

]) \tf@toc=\write5 \openout5 = `Report.toc'.

 [5] (./Report.lof [6

] [7]) \tf@lof=\write6 \openout6 = `Report.lof'.

 [8] (./Report.lot Overfull \hbox (1.74966pt too wide) in paragraph at
lines 4--4  [][] []\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 Summary of power-trains used
and/or de-vel-op-ment i n pas-sen-ger light-weight |  []

) \tf@lot=\write7 \openout7 = `Report.lot'.

 [9

] ! Undefined control sequence. <argument> Chapter \thechapter .
\Chaptername 
                                               l.121 \chapter
              {Presentation} The control sequence at the end of the top line 
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling
(e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about
whatever was undefined.
```

**AND** Here is the code from the main .tex file that calls several .tex files.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, draft]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{footnote}

\captionsetup{font=footnotesize, labelfont=sc}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\pagestyle{fancy}

\definecolor{bblue}{HTML}{A9D0F5}
\definecolor{lightbblue}{HTML}{CEF6EC}
\definecolor{darkbblue}{HTML}{4189F5}
\definecolor{ggreen}{HTML}{D8F6CE}
\definecolor{darkggreen}{HTML}{41F583}
\definecolor{verydarkggreen}{HTML}{31B404}
\definecolor{rred}{HTML}{F5A9A9}
\definecolor{verydarkrred}{HTML}{DF0101}
\definecolor{oorange}{HTML}{F5ECCE}
\definecolor{verydarkoorange}{HTML}{DF7401}
% \def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}} This is for vertical centering in tabularx.

\SetWatermarkText{DRAFT}
\SetWatermarkScale{3}
\SetWatermarkLightness{0.9}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={font={{\scriptsize}}}}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}

\author{Gerard Illana Meler}
\date{September 2016}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\small \emph{TEXT}}
\fancyhead[R]{\small TEXT}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\small \thepage}

\input{Chapters/01_Title}

\input{Chapters/02_Abstract}

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\emph{Text}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\let\Chaptermark\chaptermark % THIS IS THE ERROR SOURCE
\def\chaptermark#1{\def\Chaptername{#1}\Chaptermark{#1}} % THIS IS THE ERROR SOURCE
\fancyhead{} % THIS IS THE ERROR SOURCE
\fancyhead[L]{\small \emph{Text}} % THIS IS THE ERROR SOURCE
\fancyhead[R]{\small Text} % THIS IS THE ERROR SOURCE
\fancyfoot{} % THIS IS THE ERROR SOURCE
\fancyfoot[R]{\small \thepage} % THIS IS THE ERROR SOURCE
\fancyfoot[L]{\small \emph{Chapter \thechapter. \Chaptername}} % THIS IS THE ERROR SOURCE

\chapter{Presentation}
\externaldocument{Chapters/03_Presentation}
\input{Chapters/03_Presentation}

\chapter{Introduction}
\externaldocument{Chapters/04_Introduction}
\input{Chapters/04_Introduction}

\chapter{Experimental data}
\externaldocument{Chapters/05_Experimental_data}
\input{Chapters/05_Experimental_data}

\chapter{Analysis of the vehicle usage} \label{Analysis_of_the_vehicle_usage}
\externaldocument{Chapters/06_Analysis_of_the_vehicle_usage}
\input{Chapters/06_Analysis_of_the_vehicle_usage}

\chapter{Definition of driving patterns}
\externaldocument{Chapters/07_Definition_of_driving_patterns}
\input{Chapters/07_Definition_of_driving_patterns}

\chapter{Estimation of alternative power-train solutions}
\externaldocument{Chapters/08_Estimation_of_alternative_power_train_solutions}
\input{Chapters/08_Estimation_of_alternative_power_train_solutions}

\chapter{Impact of alternative power-trains}
\externaldocument{Chapters/09_Impact_of_alternative_power_trains}
\input{Chapters/09_Impact_of_alternative_power_trains}

\chapter{List of abbreviations}
\externaldocument{Chapters/98_List_of_abbreviations}
\input{Chapters/98_List_of_abbreviations}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{References/Bibliography_report}

\appendix

\chapter{Appendix}
\externaldocument{Chapters/99_Appendix}
\input{Chapters/99_Appendix}

\end{document}
```

Comment: i've recoded the error log insertion as a code block, since it's meant to be taken literally.  material marked as a quote on this site reflows the text; i wasn't able to reconstruct that very well.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. The only errors I get are about missing files that the document tries to input; so maybe one of your input files is the culprit. Can you invest a little bit more effort and provide a *complete* document (no reference to other documents) that shows the problem? And without loading packages that are irrelevant to the error?

Comment: in the document classes i'm most familiar with, the command is `\chaptername` with a lowercase "c"; the error message has `\Chaptername`.  it's not clear where that is coming from; most likely in a file not shown here, and in particular, `Report.lot`, which according to the log has just been input, but not completely read in.

Comment: What makes you think that `\Chaptername` is defined?

Comment: @egreg @barbarabeeton `\Chaptername` gets defined in the redefined macro `\chaptermark`. When I compile the document without the `\input`s, I get no errors.

Comment: By the way, what's the purpose of all those `\externaldocument` commands? As far as I can see they do nothing at all. Anyway, `\Chaptername` is still undefined until you issue a proper `\chapter` command, but LaTeX is trying to typeset a header and finds the problem.

Comment: why all the package commands? many are repeated, eg two graphicx, neither of which are needed as you load rotating, two subcaption, array which is already loaded by (at least) colortbl xr which you are not really using, fixltx2e which shouldn't be used with current latex (it does nothing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Analysis of the problem

The problem is that when the new page style is being defined, LaTeX is in the middle of the last page in `\listoftables`; so when `\chapter{Presentation}` is executed, a page is ejected to begin with, but `\Chaptername` has not yet been set, because `\chaptermark` is executed *after* the `\clearpage that starts the work of`\chapter`.

## Solution

Issue `\clearpage` after `\listoftables`, before `\let\Chaptermark\chaptermark`.

## Miscellaneous comments

1. You can also avoid defining `\Chaptername` and redefining `\chaptermark`: just do

   ```
   \fancyfoot[L]{\small\emph{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
   ```
2. All your `\externaldocument` commands do exactly nothing. When you do `\input{file}` it's the same as if you added the contents of `file.tex` at the spot. And LaTeX doesn't need to rely on `\externaldocument` for labels and cross-references in the document it's processing.
3. Also load `fix-cm` in order to remove the `draftwatermark` warning about font substitution. You won't need `\SetWatermarkScale{3}`.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, I fix it through egreg solution proposal. I also applied all the rest of the corrections, sorry I am not an experienced user of LaTeX and it is always welcome to learn how some aspects actually work.